# How to detect connections to specific IP addresses from home network

Tags: networking, router, ip, gaming

(The real title is "how to detect when my son is playing League of Legends".)

My home network consists of an RT-AC66U router with
the usual wireless network and a few wired connections to Linux boxes.

From a wired Linux box, is there a way I can detect when my son accesses a specific IP address (to start with) from his Windows laptop on the home network?

I am interested in solutions that use existing tools & setup, I realize that I could install OpenWrt or similar software and do what I want but that too intrusive in a privacy sense.

Comment: Automatically detect - no, or at least without coding a software to listen on the router for open connections. You can manually check that by going in the router and searching for 'Active connections' in the Status page. It should show you all connections - protocol + local IP to external IP.

Comment: @Fanatique: Thanks, I got that already, but was hoping for something along tcpdump lines than scraping the router.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It is not me who has downvoted.

Comment: @Fanatique: Sorry, I wasn't implying that. I have been using SE/SO for over 6 years and am always curious what the point of downvoting a question that seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Network switches won’t allow you to see the traffic the other computer is generating. So TCPDUMP won’t show anything. However, you can turn on ip forwarding in your Linux box and then ARP spoof your son’s machine forcing it to send all network traffic through your machine which can then be seen by tcpdump. However, encrypted traffic will remain encrypted, but all DNS requests and IP addresses will be plain text. Arpspoofing is detectable and can cause connectivity or latency issues depending on the network topology.

Comment: Another option would be to install BIND on your Linux box and configure it as a forwarding DNS server. Then change the DHCP settings on your router so it tells all computers to use your machine for DNS. Then you can tcpdump or monitor dns log files to see every DNS request for particular domains by all computers on the network. Less intrusive, more reliable, but still detectable by someone sharp.

Comment: @appleoddity: Nice idea, I already have my Linux box as dns server, so no change needed other than grepping logs. Thanks.